# SAS summary statistic from a dataset

Tags: sas, sas-macro

The dataset looks like this:

```
colx      coly    colz  
0         1       0      
0         1       1      
0         1       0
```

Required output:

```
Colname      value    count

colx         0        3
coly         1        3
colz         0        2
colz         1        1
```

The following code works perfectly...

```
ods output onewayfreqs=outfreq;

proc freq data=final;
  tables colx coly colz / nocum nofreq;
run;

data freq;
  retain colname column_value;
  set outfreq;
  colname = scan(tables, 2, ' ');
  column_Value = trim(left(vvaluex(colname)));
  keep colname column_value frequency percent;
run;
```

... but I believe that's not efficient. Say I have 1000 columns, running prof freq on all 1000 columns is not efficient. Is there any other efficient way with out using the proc freq that accomplishes my desired output?

Comment: I think that's as good as it gets. You can use the `_all_` keyword instead of typing all the column names. (`tables _all_ / nocum nofreq;`)

Comment: In what sense is this not efficient? You're only running proc freq once. It might be possible to write an equivalent data step that uses slightly less memory, but unless that's proving to be a limiting factor for you I wouldn't bother.

Comment: I felt  like the odsoutput with proc freq is slowing down and creating huge logs and outputs. think of 10,000 variables and million records. I felt there should be another way of accomplishing this and arrays seems to be a great fit

Answer (score 1):

One of the most efficient mechanisms for computing frequency counts is through a hash object set up for reference counting via the `suminc` tag.

The SAS documentation for "Hash Object - Maintaining Key Summaries" demonstrates the technique for a single variable.  The following example goes one step further and computes for each variable specified in an array.  The `suminc:'one'` specifies that each use of `ref` will add the value of `one` to an internal reference sum.  While iterating over the distinct keys for output, the frequency count is extracted via the `sum` method.

```
* one million data values;

data have;
  array v(1000);
  do row = 1 to 1000;
    do index = 1 to dim(v);
      v(index) = ceil(100*ranuni(123));
    end;
    output;
  end;
  keep v:;
  format v: 4.;
run;

* compute frequency counts via .ref();    

data freak_out(keep=name value count);
  length name $32 value 8;

  declare hash bins(ordered:'a', suminc:'one');
  bins.defineKey('name', 'value');
  bins.defineData('name', 'value');
  bins.defineDone();

  one = 1;

  do until (end_of_data);
    set have end=end_of_data;
    array v v1-v1000;
    do index = 1 to dim(v);
      name = vname(v(index));
      value = v(index);
      bins.ref();
    end;
  end;

  declare hiter out('bins');
  do while (out.next() = 0);
    bins.sum(sum:count);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Note `Proc FREQ` uses standard grammars, variables can be a mixed of character and numeric, and has lots of additional features that are specified through options.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most time consuming part in your code is generation of the ODS report. You can transpose the data before applying the freq. The below example does the task for 1000 rows with 1000 variables in few seconds. If you do it using ODS it may take much longer.

```
data dummy;
    array colNames [1000] col1-col1000;
    do line = 1 to 1000;
        do j = 1 to dim(colNames);
            colNames[j] = int(rand("uniform")*100);
        end;
        output;
    end;
    drop j;
run;

proc transpose 
    data = dummy 
    out = dummyTransposed (drop = line rename = (_name_ = colName col1 = value))
    ;
    var col1-col1000;
    by line;
run;

proc freq data = dummyTransposed noprint;
    tables colName*value / out = result(drop = percent);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this statement from the comments is the real problem.

> I felt like the odsoutput with proc freq is slowing down and creating
>   huge logs and outputs. think of 10,000 variables and million records.
>   I felt there should be another way of accomplishing this and arrays
>   seems to be a great fit

You can tell ODS not to produce the printed output if you don't want it.

```
ods exclude all ;
ods output onewayfreqs=outfreq;
proc freq data=final;
  tables colx coly colz / nocum nofreq;
run;
ods exclude none ;
```