# Out of Memory using PROC FREQ

Tags: sas

I have approximately 1,000,000 rows and 25 columns of data and I'm trying to return a list of column names, the number of distinct values and whether there are missing values.

I am not able to directly code in column names in PROC SQL and count distinct as I have numerous data sets with different column names and I'm trying to automatically return the desired outcome for all tables with one piece of code.

I've tried running the following code

```
proc freq nlevels data= &DATASET_NAME;
    ods output nlevels=nlevels ;
    tables _all_ NOPRINT;
run;
```

This returns an out of memory error. Is there another way to achieve the result, avoiding the out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary to input column name by *table _all_*, but it possibly makes out of memory by inputting all columns at the same time, try to separate column to do proc freq and then combine results:

```
proc sql;
   create table name as
   select name from dictionary.columns where libname='SASHELP' and memname='CLASS';
quit;

data want;
run;

data _null_;
   set name;
   call execute(
      'proc freq data=class nlevels;
       table '||name||';
       ods output nlevels=nlevels;
       run;
       data want;
          set want nlevels;
       run;'
    );
run;
```

Comment: One downside is that this will read the input table many times rather than just once. Memory permitting, it would be a lot faster to do a few columns at a time.

Comment: When processing a data set many times, open it first with the SASFILE statement. 1M rows by 25 columns of $40 length variables is only ~1GB+ RAM.

Comment: Thanks, your code has successfully created the correct output. The only issue is it attempts to create a "very large" HTML output which slows down the process considerably and needs to be manually declined. Is there a way to suppress the HTML output after creating the WANT table?

Comment: Close all ODS destinations, `ODS _ALL_ CLOSE`, prior to opening only ODS OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to [SAS summary statistic from a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604216/sas-summary-statistic-from-a-dataset)

The answers cover techniques for

- transpose + freq
- hash
- freq w/ ODS exclude+output